# CSS row-gap like column-gap?

Tags: html, css

Using [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/), I tried making the same thing, but with gaps between the images. So I simply changed the column-gap property to 3px, but obviously, that only works horizontally. Is there any thing like row-gap or anything so I also can have a 3px gap vertically between the images? Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yegMRK).

```
column-gap: 3px;
row-gap: 3px /* ??? */
```

EDIT: How this image grid works is by simply using:

```
line-height: 0;
```

and

```
column-count: <any value>
column-gap: 0;
```

on the container/parent and with

```
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
```

on the images/children.

HTML

```
<section id="photos">
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/394/205/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/246/306/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/356/398/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/388/367/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/316/354/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/348/216/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/342/371/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/327/201/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/310/225/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/210/238/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/255/247/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/334/361/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/399/374/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/288/215/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/216/227/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/311/200/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/371/266/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/362/374/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/333/220/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/297/374/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/377/342/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/306/243/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/303/223/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/384/238/cats" alt="pretty kitty"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/396/272/cats" alt="pretty kitty">
</section>
```

CSS

```
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;

   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   3px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      3px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           3px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

EDIT 2: I have tried line-height, but it only seems to use half the space and line-height as well as margin-bottom and padding-bottom will leave an extra space at the very bottom of every column, and besides that, you can't really change the color of them, border-bottom would be more ideal for color though, but also, it leaves a space at the end of every column aswell.

Comment: Please post enough code in the question in order for someone to answer this without clicking links.

Comment: @Popnoodles I also edited the codepen, with what I have tried

Comment: You're trying to build a grid out of one element. This is going to end badly; I recommend using more markup to flesh out the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no rows. Add a margin to the images.

```
#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Comment: That will create a 3px space at the bottom of every column, I want it only *between* the images.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out how to overcome that. I can't see any more of your layout than what you gave in a link, so I can't help with it.

Comment: well i did that in your codepen and its working as margin on each image bottom, so row between each image vertically and horizontally are the same..

Comment: Perhaps a padding instead of a margin is more suitable for you? ...But there will be no difference to how it ooks so I have no idea why I would suggest such a thing!